Fubini-Study form is invariant under the action of $U(n+1)$
I am doing an exercise about the Fubini-Study form but i have some problem to prove the following fact : The Fubini-Study form $\omega$ is invariant under the standard action of $U(n+1)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^n$.
The point is that the Fubini-Study metric is defined in the exercise as the only Riemannian metric $\rho$ such that $$\rho_{\pi(x)} (d \pi_x u, d \pi_x v) = \langle u, v \rangle$$ where $\pi : \mathbb{S}^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ is the Hopf fibration, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the usual scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ and $u,v$ are vectors in $\operatorname{Ker}(d \pi_x)^\bot$. (This result is due to the fact that $(\operatorname{Ker} d \pi_x)^{\bot}$ is isomorphic to the tangeant space $T_x \mathbb{CP}^n$.) The form $\omega$ is defined by the map \begin{align*}
\omega_x : T_x \mathbb{CP}^n \times T_x \mathbb{CP}^n &\to \mathbb{R}\\
(u,v) &\mapsto \rho_x (i \cdot u, v)
\end{align*}
for all $x \in \mathbb{CP}^n$ and where $\cdot$ denotes the multiplication by $i$.
I proved that this map is a alternating 2-form which is non-degenerate, I also proved that the De Rham cohomology class of $\omega^{\wedge n}$ is non-trivial. But I am stuck on proving that it is invariant under the action of $U(n+1)$. And I am not supposed to use the expression of the Fubini-Study metric that we find in every book.
Does someone has any references, hints... ?

$U(n+1)$ acts on $S^{2n-1} \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ by isometries. This induces an action on $\mathbb{C}P^n$. You just need to show that this action is also by isometries.

Hint: If you view $T_xS^{2n+1}$ as a linear subspace of $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, then you can verify that $(\text{Ker\ } d\pi_x)^\perp$ always is ac complex subspace of $\mathbb C^{n+1}$. Next, you can show that the derivative of action of $A\in U(n+1)$ maps $(\text{Ker\ } d\pi_x)^\perp$ to $(\text{Ker\ } d\pi_{Ax})^\perp$ and restricts to a complex linear map on these spaces (since $A$ is complex linear). Then the fact that $\omega$ is preserved becomes a simple consequence of the fact that the Fubini-Study metric is preserved.
